# Package 'javax.sound.midi' is declared in module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javasound

When I add this in my Java app in IntelliJ

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
```

I get this error
"Package 'javax.sound.midi' is declared in module 'java.desktop', but module 'com.example.music' does not read it"

I have read online that javax.sound is part of the OpenJDK 20 ...

Have you an idea of why I get this error

Ed

Comment: Does your project use a module-info.java file? If so, can you show it's contents?

Comment: I see this in the module-info.java module 

com.example.music {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    opens com.example.music to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.music;
}

Comment: I think you need to include a reference to java.desktop in your module-info file. I'm not sure of the exact form/syntax, though. Perhaps it's simple adding the line "requires java.desktop;"? I'd have to fiddle to know for sure.

Comment: You are right @PhilFreihofner I added `requires java.desktop;` in module-info.java and it works! Thank you very much

Comment: I'm going to post an answer or if you like you can post your own. Main thing is to have an answer designated so that others don't think this issue still needs solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posted after engaging in clarifying questions.)

Sometimes an error message like this occurs because the required module is not listed in the `module-info.java` file.

According to the OP, adding the following line to `module-info.java`:

```
requires java.desktop;
```

solved the issue.